# ThreeJs OrbitControl import version from CDN

Tags: javascript, three.js, cdn, orbitcontrols

I'm using threejs from CDN and i need OrbitControl too, but if I use the same lastest version 0.148.0 to import both Three and OrbitControl it don't work:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/build/three.module.js'
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
```

To make it work I need to use FOR OrbitControl Only the lower 0.126.1 version

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/build/three.module.js'
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
```

WHY is so? Thank you very much, i'm a total beginnner

Comment: What do you get when you visit that address? https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js Do you see a "cannot find" error? Because I'm getting the OrbitControls `.js` file with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need an import map when importing latest `three.js` releases. Rewrite your imports like so:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

And in your HTML, put this in your header:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148.0/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

In this way, the imports will look exactly like in the official examples.

The import map will tell the browser how to resolve the bare module specifier `three`. More information in the official [Installation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation) guide.